# What's a more concise way of finding text in a set of files?

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I currently use the following command, but it's a little unwieldy to type.  What's a shorter alternative?

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec grep 'sometext' '{}' \; -print
```

Here are my requirements:

- limit to a file extension (I use SVN and don't want to be searching through all those .svn directories)
- can default to the current directory, but it's nice to be able to specify a different directory
- must be recursive

**UPDATE:** Here's my best solution so far:

```
grep -r 'sometext' * --include='*.txt'
```

**UPDATE #2:** After using grep for a bit, I realized that I like the output of my first method better. So, I followed the suggestions of several responders and simply made a shell script and now I call that with two parameters (extension and text to find).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

grep has -r (recursive) and --include (to search only in files and directories matching a pattern).

Comment: It's worth noting that these options are non-portable across unices.

Answer (score 3):

If its too unweildy, write a script that does it and put it in your personal bin directory.  I have a 'fif' script which searches source files for text, basically just doing a single find like you have here:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -f  # disable pathname expansion

pattern="-iname *.[chsyl] -o -iname *.[ch]pp -o -iname *.hh -o -iname *.cc
-o -iname *.java -o -iname *.inl"
prune=""
moreargs=true
while $moreargs && [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
    -h)
        pattern="-iname *.h -o -iname *.hpp -o -iname *.hh"
        shift
        ;;
    -prune)
        prune="-name $2 -prune -false -o $prune"
        shift
        shift
        ;;
    *)
        moreargs=false;
        ;;
    esac
done

find . $prune $pattern | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs grep "$@"
```

it started life as a single-line script and got features added over the years as I needed them.

Answer (score 3):

This is much more efficient since it invokes `grep` many fewer times, though it's hard to say it's more succinct:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'sometext' /dev/null
```

Notes:

/`find -print0` and `xargs -0` makes pathnames with embedded blanks work correctly.

The `/dev/null` argument makes sure grep always prepends a filename.

Comment: How about `-H` (`--with-filename`) instead of that workaround?

Comment: `find . -name '*.txt' -exec grep 'sometext' /dev/null {} +` would be a more concise and efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Install [`ack`](http://petdance.com/ack/) and use

```
ack -aG'\.txt$' 'sometext'
```

Comment: This solution is the most succinct, but unfortunately requires an install of ack and is even less portable that a straight find or grep command.

Comment: ack is a single Perl script.  You can download it with wget and put it in your ~/bin directory.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Andy: it's still a dependency, regardless of how easy it is to get and install

Answer (score 3):

I second ephemient's suggestion of ack. I'm writing this post to highlight a particular issue.

In response to jgormley (in the comments): `ack` is available as a single file which will work wherever the right Perl version is installed (which is everywhere).

Given that on non-Linux platforms `grep` regularly does not accept `-R`, arguably using `ack` is *more* portable.

Comment: Plus, ack will run on Windows, so you can do this where you don't have find and grep.

Answer (score 2):

I use zsh, which has recursive globbing. If you needed to look at specific filetypes, the following would be equivalent to your example:

```
grep 'sometext' **/*.txt
```

If you don't care about the filetype, the -r option will be better:

```
grep -r 'sometext' *
```

Although, A minor tweak to your original example will give you exactly what you want:

```
find . -name '*.txt' \! -wholename '*/.svn/*' -exec grep 'sometext' '{}' \; -print
```

If this is something you do frequently, make it a function (put this in your shell config):

```
function grep_no_svn {
    find . -name "${2:-*}" \! -wholename '*/.svn/*' -exec grep "$1" '{}' \; -print
}
```

Where the first argument to the function is the text you're searching for. So:

```
$ grep_here_no_svn "sometext"
```

Or:

```
$ grep_here_no_svn "sometext" "*.txt"
```

Comment: Globbing will run into the limit on the command line size once your filename list gets too long.  Combinations of find and xargs won't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script (in bash or whatever -- I have one in Groovy) and place it on the path.  E.g.

```
$ myFind.sh txt targetString
```

where myFind.sh is:

```
find . -name "*.$1" -exec grep $2 {} \; -print
```

Answer (score 0):

I usualy avoid the "man find" by using `grep $(find . -name "*,txt")`

Answer (score 0):

You say that you like the output of your method (using find) better. The only difference I can see between them is that grepping multiple files will put the filename on the front.

You can always (in GNU grep, but you must be using that or -r and --include wouldn't work) turn the filename off by using -h (--no-filename). The opposite, for anyone who does want filenames but has to use find for some other reason, is -H (--with-filename).